# Invalid value when using floats

Tags: php, floating-point, floating-accuracy

The following operation give out the wrong result.

```
$First      = '45.4000';
$Second     = '4.6800000000';
$Third      = '50.00';

echo ( $First + $Second ) - $Third;
```

**OUTPUT:** 0.079999999999998

**Expected Output:** 0.08

I am looking on how to get the right result, without using number_format/sprintf ...etc.

As this issue is affecting multiple places in my code & have to go over everything & formatting it is a pain.

Comment: What is wrong with `number_format/sprintf` etc..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score -1):

As a "quick fix", change the `precision` setting in your php.ini file. [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision).

By default, it is 14, which is more than you need almost all the time (and if you need that much precision you'd be using a dedicated math library). Change it to something like 4, and the result will be rounded to that length - note that you can still override this with `number_format` on a case-by-case basis if you need to.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
$First      = '45.4000';
$Second     = '4.6800000000';
$Third      = '50.00';

$sk = ( $First + $Second ) - $Third;

echo round($sk,4);

?>
```